# What are some efficient ways to manage web socket connections?

Tags: rest, http, websocket, web-development-server, wss

I am working on an application that is solely based on web sockets for all kinds of data transmission to the server. However, I am concerned that on scaling it might be difficult to manage all connections on a small server, considering I am out to saving server costs.

1. Assuming that the app will scale to level of millions of users, I do not want the stale connections to take up memory and CPU.
2. Also the client has to send data from time to time to the server, just like google maps updates our locations when we are navigating from our origin to our destination.

How do I manage my server system resources efficiently and still acheive almost real-time data updation? Are there any good ways to manage connnection/re-use connections/dump and re-connect, anything that will help reduce server load and cost on server side.

Comment: Lets be honest: handling millions of simultaneous users on one machine is not going to happen. Regardless of tech stack. Start thinking about distributed design.

Comment: What are your *real* load requirements? Millions of concurrent users is basically reserved for the most popular applications in the world (even a very large scale commercial website is unlikely to crack 100k concurrents), and they don't need to worry about small servers.

Comment: In real life, the user count wont go to that spike, but I want to make the app in such a way that it can hypothetically scale to that limit.